# Form_tag routing error after unsuccessful submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller, routes

I have an index page with a partial form to submit new records to Package model. I keep this form in the index page, so the user doesn't need to leave the page when repeating this action, several times.
In the same page I have a form_tag fir multiple updates for the same controller, namely packages_controller.
Everything works fine, except the following: when hit the update button, going to the form BUT instead of submitting I go back (with the browser) and try to select other records to be updated then I have a routing error:

```
Routing Error
```

No route matches [PUT] "/projects/47/orderlines/18/packages"

My index page looks like this:

```html
 <% if current_user %> 
  <%= render "packages/form" %>
 <% end %>

<% if @packages.count >= 1 %>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="selectAll"></th>
  <th>Packed </th>
      <th>#No.</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Gross weight</th>
      <th>Length</th>
      <th>Width</th>
      <th>Height</th>
   <th></th>
   <th>Container</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<%= form_tag edit_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path, method: :get do %>
  <tbody>
    <% for package in @packages %>
  <% if package.packed== true %>
  <% @label_type="success" %>
  <% else %>
  <% @label_type="default" %>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= check_box_tag "package_ids[]", package.id %></td>
   <td><span class="label label-<%= @label_type %>"><% if package.packed==true %>Packed<% else %>Unpacked<% end %></span></td>
        <td><%= package.package_no %></td>
        <td><%= package.package_type %></td>
        <td><%= package.gross_weight %></td>
        <td><%= package.length %></td>
        <td><%= package.width %></td>
        <td><%= package.height %></td>
  <% if @orderline.packages.count >= 1  %>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', [package.orderline.project, package.orderline, package],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
 
  <td><%= @containers.find(package.container_id).container_id if package.packed %></td>    
  <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= submit_tag "Add to container", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
<br />

<%= will_paginate %>
<br>
```

And the multiple_edit form

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <%= form_tag update_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path, method: :put do %>
  <ul>
   <% @packages.each do |package| %>
   <li>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "package_ids[]", package.id %>
    <%= package.package_no %>
    <%= package.container_id %>
     <% package.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= fields_for :package do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :package_no %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :package_no, :class => "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :container_id %><br />
    <%= select_tag 'package[container_id]', options_from_collection_for_select(@project.containers, 'id', 'container_id', default_blank: true), prompt: "- Select container -", :class => "form-control" %>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :packed %><br />
         <%= f.select :packed, [["Packed", true], ["Unpacked", false]],{ prompt: "- Packing -"},{ :class => "form-control" } %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
   <br />
   <%= submit_tag "Update", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

And the packages controller edit_multiple actions:

```html
  
  def edit_multiple
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @packages = Package.find(params[:package_ids])
  end
  
  def update_multiple
    @packages = Package.find(params[:package_ids])
    @packages.reject! do |package|
      package.update_attributes(package_params.reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
    end
    if @packages.empty?
      redirect_to project_orderline_packages_url
    else
      @package = Package.new(package_params)
      render "edit_multiple"
    end
  end
```

packages_controller create action:

```html
def create
    project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    orderline = project.orderlines.find(params[:orderline_id])
      @package = orderline.packages.new(package_params)
      @package.save
    
    
    if @package.save
      flash[:success] = "Package(s) was successfully added."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'new'
    end
```

And my routes:

```html
resources :projects do
  resources :containers
  resources :orderlines do
     resources :packages do 
       collection do 
         put :packed
         get :edit_multiple
         put :update_multiple
       end
     end
   end
end
```

I just added my routes here:

- edit_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path    GET /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/edit_multiple(.:format) 
  packages#edit_multiple
  update_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path  PUT /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/update_multiple(.:format)
  packages#update_multiple
  project_orderline_packages_path  GET /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages(.:format)
  packages#index
  POST /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages(.:format)
  packages#create
  new_project_orderline_package_path   GET /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/new(.:format)
  packages#new
  edit_project_orderline_package_path  GET /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/:id/edit(.:format)
  packages#edit
  project_orderline_package_path   GET /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/:id(.:format)
  packages#show
  PATCH    /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/:id(.:format)
  packages#update
  PUT  /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/:id(.:format)
  packages#update
  DELETE   /projects/:project_id/orderlines/:orderline_id/packages/:id(.:format)

Comment: did you check your routes? localhost:3000/routes, what does it say regarding this PUT route? Sorry, but i just didn't spot a mistake so quickly...

Comment: this route doesn't exist, which is correct in a sense that PUT should be for update_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path, ...for project_orderline_packages_path I have only the GET and POST

Comment: There seems to be an error when calling this form with this route...update_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path, method: :put do . Rails tries this route projects/47/orderlines/18/packages which you have not defined.

Comment: In case I refresh the index page of the Packages, and then I submit the form than it is ok

Answer (score 0):

your form_tag code is `update_multiple_project_orderline_packages_path`
I think it should be  `update_multiple_project_orderline_package_path(project_id, orderline_id, package_id)`

I am not 100% sure with my statement above, because you gave scrambled Rails Routes, hard to read

and your form action seems goes to `packages#edit_multiple` controller
so paste your `edit_multiple` method, not `create` method

are you implementing your scenario above with javascript, or just plain HTML?